# Expectation of normal and log normal distribution

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $X \sim N(\mu_x, \sigma_x^2)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_y, \sigma_y^2)$, with correlation $\rho$.

How do I find $$E[Xe^Y]$$?

I tried a bunch of things without result. I'm also interested in "general" methods if they exists

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $X$ and $Y$ are **jointly** normal.  Then $$E[X|Y] = \mu_x + \dfrac{\rho \sigma_x}{\sigma_y} (Y - \mu_y)$$
and then
$$ E[X e^Y] = E[E[X|Y] e^Y] = \ldots $$
Now use the moment generating function for $Y$:
$$E[e^{tY}] = \exp(t \mu_y + t^2 \sigma_y^2/2)$$
and its derivative with respect to $t$, which is $E[Y e^{tY}]$.

Comment: +1 Thank you. I get $$e^{\mu_y + \sigma_Y^2/2} (\mu_x + Cov(X,Y))$$. But I do not understand the second equality, when you substitute $X$ for $E(X \mid Y)$ inside the expectation

Comment: $E[Z] = E[E[Z|Y]]$ is a fundamental property of conditional expectation (the  "law of total expectation").  Apply that to $Z = X e^Y$ and note that
$E[X e^Y|Y] = E[X|Y] e^Y$.

Comment: Oh, of course, I had a lapsus. Thank you, perfect :)